# Programming Android search to work like iOS version

Tags: android, search

I am new to Android programming and I am trying to make an android version of an iOS app I have. In the iOS version I have a search bar controller and table view. The table view is initially populated with a list of data split into 4 sections. when any of the items are clicked it will push to a detail view with full screen image and title of the item. The search would then filter this list and the results would push in the same way.

I am looking to recreate this for android but when looking at exaples etc it never seems to be along the same lines.

Does anyone know how I can do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your question is really vague (you talk about the search, the sectioned ListView, the fullScreen detail,..) I cannot give you all the needed answer, that would mean a full application.

First of all I don't think that "I want to make it work like iOS" is the best approach, as your users are used to Android search and not the iOS one, they will be lost and find your app un-natural

If you are looking to create a search widget, you should use the Search Widget in the ActionBar (use ActionBarSherlock for pre-Honeycomb devices)

All the documentation can be found here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/search-dialog.html

[image]

There are also many of links on this page and if you still have issues, the best would be to come back with a precise question

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the options menu from XML
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.options_menu, menu);

    // Get the SearchView and set the searchable configuration
    SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
    SearchView searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.menu_search).getActionView();
    // Assumes current activity is the searchable activity
    searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));
    searchView.setIconifiedByDefault(false); // Do not iconify the widget; expand it by default

    return true;
}
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the link, I could have put my iOS code on here but I though that may not have been helpful. It's basically two screens I'm looking for searchable list view and detail view

Comment: I cannot give you support for your full application. I added some code to display the search Widget, then you should filter your ListView, notify your Adapter that data changed to update it (notifyDataSetChanged) and then display the result in a full screen layout.. So there are basically 4 or 5 questions you should easily fond informations in developer guide. I helped for the first one, but you understand I cannot write a full application in a single answer